# Network Manager (as well as wicd) don't connect to Wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I experience an error on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Thar with my Wi-Fi.
After installing Ubuntu some months ago, I did not have any problems.
Just recently I followed this guide on what one should do after installing this distribution (http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr).
After rebooting my PC was unable to connect to Wi-Fi through Network.Manager and kept asking for the password (as described in countless threads in this forum as well). Googling the problem I tried lots of stuff to fix it following instructions in this and other forums, including:
- Removing Network Manager and using WICD instead
- installing gnome-keyring
- Allowing the connection to be used by every user and so on
- Clearing my IP-Tables
- Deleting the connection, rebooting and setting it up anew.

And yet: Every time I try to connect to my Wifi, NWM-Applet prompts to enter a passphrase. The passphrase is saved. Wether I just click enter or retype the passphrase and press enter .. the promt just comes again.
I can connect normally by cable and every other device connects normally to the wifi, as well as my windows boot system on the same pc (from which I am typing right now ;)).

What can I do to fix this problem? Where should I look for solutions?

Thank you very much for your help!

PS: I use Xubuntu since years on my Netbook, but I am quite new to Ubuntu.

EDIT: I reinstalled the whole system, but after update und upgrade the problem reappeared -.-

Answer (score 0):

I have same like this, I use 'System settings' : 'software and updates' : 'additional drivers' tab - in my case - Broadcom wifi driver. After installation, reboot and it's working.

Comment: Tried that, no aditional drivers are available for my machine.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to sudo apt-get install nmcli. Nmcli is a network manager thru command line **N**etwork **M**anager **c**ommand **li**ne is what the name stands for. I used recently because it was faster and easier than the graphical IDEs. The connection to wifi is one, short line...

`nmcli dev wifi connect "name of network" password 'someAsc11comb0'`.

Hope that helps you.

helpful links
http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-get-started-nmcli/   ##basic instruction
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80126/how-to-connect-to-internet-using-nmcli     ##issues and problems

Comment: Hm, for some reason, the package for nmcli cannot be found. Tried to google this issue, but did not find a solution.

Comment: /usr/bin/nmcli is included in the network-manager package.  I found it this way:   dpkg -S /usr/bin/nmcli

Comment: Be careful about advice that you find concerning Ubuntu or any Linux distro.  Some of it may not have been tested on an environment similar to yours.